# Kubuntu 22.04 won't boot after installing Xanmod Kernal

Tags: boot, kubuntu, secure-boot, lutris, b43

I installed Xanmod Kernal while setting up Lutris, however when I rebooted, the system wouldn't boot. I thought it might be because I have secure boot enabled, so I went and disabled secure boot but it still won't start up. The messages displayed are:

b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)

mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

Dev loop16: unable to read RDB block 8

I'd prefer not to reinstall kubuntu if possible.

edit: I just remembered, when installing xanmod kernal I didn't use the -lts and when it downloaded, it said the version was depreciated so it was loading something else instead, I ignored it since it seemed it worked fine, and it gave the OK, but that might have something to do with this, is it possible to load the default kernel pre-boot?

Answer (score 1):

so you are not even getting the grub menu allowing you to choose Advanced mode and then choosing a different kernel? Because when you install a kernel, Ubuntu keep two or more old kernels installed incase something goes wrong with the new kernel (I use xanmod 5.18 d in Ubuntu 22.04; I doubt it is the source of the problem)

Those errors look like something more fundamental; the wrong boot device or a bad disk. Investigate BIOS for boot device choice (sometimes F12 at boot is a shortcut to boot device selection).

If that doesn't fix it, you will have to learn how to recover your boot partition. You will need a live USB and some googling.

Comment: I didn't get a grub menu at all, I booted the try kubuntu with USB and ran the boot repair, which brought back the grub menu, but it still wouldn't boot, went to bios and switched back to secure boot because I realized I must for some reason have not formatted as GPT, then it wouldn't boot because kernel wasn't loaded, so I went to advanced settings, switched from xanmod to default and it worked. Went back to see if I could reinstall xanmod-lts and the but the apt-key is depreciated.

Comment: You sound a bit all over the place. You can not boot xanmod with secure boot, because it is not a signed kernel, so you should turn it off. The warning at the apt key being deprecated is nothing to do with booting.